# Adding arrays using YMM instructions using gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, g++, avx

I want to run the following code (in Intel syntax) in gcc (AT&T syntax).

```
; float a[128], b[128], c[128];
; for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
; Assume that a, b and c are aligned by 32
      xor ecx, ecx              ; Loop counter i = 0
L:    vmovaps ymm0, [b+rcx]     ; Load 8 elements from b
      vaddps ymm0,ymm0,[c+rcx]  ; Add  8 elements from c    
      vmovaps [a+rcx], ymm0     ; Store result in a
      add ecx,32                ; 8 elements * 4 bytes = 32 
      cmp ecx, 512              ; 128 elements * 4 bytes = 512 
      jb L                      ;Loop
```

Code is from [Optimizing subroutines in assembly language](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf).

The code I've written so far is:

```
static inline void addArray(float *a, float *b, float *c) {
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "nop                            \n"
    "xor        %%ecx, %%ecx        \n" //;Loop counter set to 0
    "loop: \n\t"
    "vmovaps    %1, %%ymm0          \n" //;Load 8 elements from b  <== WRONG
    "vaddps     %2, %%ymm0, %%ymm0  \n" //;Add  8 elements from c  <==WRONG
    "vmovaps    %%ymm0, %0          \n" //;Store result in a
    "add        0x20, %%ecx         \n" //;8 elemtns * 4 bytes = 32 (0x20)
    "cmp        0x200,%%ecx         \n" //;128 elements * 4 bytes = 512 (0x200)
    "jb         loop                \n" //;Loop"
    "nop                            \n"
        : "=m"(a)                       //Outputs       
        : "m"(b), "m"(c)                //Inputs
        : "%ecx","%ymm0"                //Modifies ECX and YMM0
    );
}
```

The lines marked as "wrong" generate: (except from gdb disassemble)

```
0x0000000000000b78 <+19>:   vmovaps -0x10(%rbp),%ymm0
0x0000000000000b7d <+24>:   vaddps -0x18(%rbp),%ymm0,%ymm0
```

I want to get something like this (I guess):

```
vmovaps -0x10(%rbp,%ecx,%0x8),%ymm0
```

But I do not know how to specify %ecx as my index register.

Can you help me, please?

**EDIT**

I've tried (%1, %%ecx):

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "nop                            \n"
    "xor        %%ecx, %%ecx        \n" //;Loop counter set to 0
    "loop: \n\t"
    "vmovaps    (%1, %%rcx), %%ymm0         \n" //;Load 8 elements from b  <== MODIFIED HERE
    "vaddps     %2, %%ymm0, %%ymm0  \n" //;Add  8 elements from c 
    "vmovaps    %%ymm0, %0          \n" //;Store result in a
    "add        0x20, %%ecx         \n" //;8 elemtns * 4 bytes = 32 (0x20)
    "cmp        0x200,%%ecx         \n" //;128 elements * 4 bytes = 512 (0x200)
    "jb         loop                \n" //;Loop"
    "nop                            \n"
        : "=m"(a)                       //Outputs       
        : "m"(b), "m"(c)                //Inputs
        : "%ecx","%ymm0"                //Modifies ECX and YMM0
    );
```

And I got:

```
inline1.cpp: Assembler messages:
inline1.cpp:90: Error: found '(', expected: ')'
inline1.cpp:90: Error: junk `(%rbp),%rcx)' after expression
```

Comment: There is no need to use assembly for this, gcc has vector builtins and supports intrinsics too.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just need to learn how to use ASM.

Comment: Use an `r` constraint. Also, don't forget to add a `memory` clobber. For best effect do not bind `ecx` and `ymm0`, and also leave the zeroing to the compiler. Not to mention aligning loop targets. Of course as I already said you should not be using assembly for this.

Comment: The exercise here is to code in asm using gcc. I know I could do the same algorithm it in plain c using intrinsics. I know how to code it in Intel/Visual Studio syntax. (the original code). What I am trying to accomplish here is to use gcc. Having that in mind, I want to do the loop in assembler. I do not know how to index using ecx, even with the r constraint...

Comment: `(%1, %%ecx)` for example. Also note you can switch gcc to intel syntax mode.

Comment: Good call. I tried "vmovaps  (%1, %%ecx), %%ymm0" and resulted in a compilation error.

Comment: You actually need `%%rcx` since you seem to be in 64 bit mode (missed that) **and** you still need to use a register constraint as I have told you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134304/discussion-between-chocksmith-and-jester).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to translate this literally into GAS inline assembly. In AT&T syntax, the syntax is:

```
displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)
```

which would produce something akin to:

```
movl  -4(%ebp, %ecx, 4), %eax
```

or in your case:

```
vmovaps  -16(%rsp, %ecx, 0), %ymm0
```

The problem is, when you use a memory constraint (`m`), the inline assembler is going to emit the following wherever you write `%n` (where `n` is the number of the input/output):

```
-16(%rsp)
```

There is no way to manipulate the above into the form you actually want. You can write:

```
(%1, %%rcx)
```

but this will produce:

```
(-16(%rsp),%rcx)
```

which is clearly wrong. There is no way to get the offset register *inside* of those parentheses, where it belongs, since `%n` is emitting the whole `-16(%rsp)` as a chunk.

Of course, this is not really an issue, since you write inline assembly to get *speed*, and there's nothing speedy about loading from memory. You should have the inputs in a register, and when you use a register constraint for the input/output (`r`), you don't have a problem. Notice that this will require modifying your code slightly

Other things wrong with your inline assembly include:

1. Numeric literals begin with `$`.
2. Instructions should have size suffixes, like `l` for 32-bit and `q` for 64-bit.
3. You are clobbering memory when you write through `a`, so you should have a `memory` clobber.
4. The `nop` instructions at the beginning and the end are completely pointless. They aren't even aligning the branch target.
5. Every line should really end with a tab character (`\t`), in addition to a new-line (`\n`), so that you get proper alignment when you inspect the disassembly.

Here is my version of the code:

```
void addArray(float *a, float *b, float *c) {
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "xorl       %%ecx, %%ecx                \n\t" // Loop counter set to 0
    "loop:                                  \n\t"
    "vmovaps    (%1,%%rcx), %%ymm0          \n\t" // Load 8 elements from b
    "vaddps     (%2,%%rcx), %%ymm0, %%ymm0  \n\t" // Add  8 elements from c
    "vmovaps    %%ymm0, (%0,%%rcx)          \n\t" // Store result in a
    "addl       $0x20,  %%ecx               \n\t" // 8 elemtns * 4 bytes = 32 (0x20)
    "cmpl       $0x200, %%ecx               \n\t" // 128 elements * 4 bytes = 512 (0x200)
    "jb         loop"                             // Loop"
        :                                         // Outputs       
        : "r" (a), "r" (b), "r" (c)               // Inputs
        : "%ecx", "%ymm0", "memory"               // Modifies ECX, YMM0, and memory
    );
}
```

This causes the compiler to emit the following:

```
addArray(float*, float*, float*):
        xorl       %ecx, %ecx                
     loop:                                  
        vmovaps    (%rsi,%rcx), %ymm0           # b
        vaddps     (%rdx,%rcx), %ymm0, %ymm0    # c
        vmovaps    %ymm0, (%rdi,%rcx)           # a
        addl       $0x20,  %ecx               
        cmpl       $0x200, %ecx               
        jb         loop
        vzeroupper
        retq
```

Or, in the more familiar Intel syntax:

```
addArray(float*, float*, float*):
        xor     ecx, ecx
   loop:
        vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi + rcx]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdx + rcx]
        vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdi + rcx], ymm0
        add     ecx, 32
        cmp     ecx, 512
        jb      loop
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

In the System V 64-bit calling convention, the first three parameters are passed in the `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx` registers, so the code doesn't need to move the parameters into registers—they are already there.

But you are not using input/output constraints to their fullest. You don't *need* `rcx` to be used as the counter. Nor do you need to use `ymm0` as the scratch register. If you let the compiler pick which free registers to use, it will make the code more efficient. You also won't need to provide an explicit clobber list:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

void addArray(float *a, float *b, float *c) {
  uint64_t temp = 0;
  __m256   ymm;
  __asm__ __volatile__(
      "loop:                        \n\t"
      "vmovaps    (%3,%0), %1       \n\t" // Load 8 elements from b
      "vaddps     (%4,%0), %1, %1   \n\t" // Add  8 elements from c
      "vmovaps    %1, (%2,%0)       \n\t" // Store result in a
      "addl       $0x20,  %0        \n\t" // 8 elemtns * 4 bytes = 32 (0x20)
      "cmpl       $0x200, %0        \n\t" // 128 elements * 4 bytes = 512 (0x200)
      "jb         loop"                   // Loop
    : "+r" (temp), "=x" (ymm)
    : "r" (a), "r" (b), "r" (c)
    : "memory"
    );
}
```

Of course, as has been mentioned in the comments, this entire exercise is a waste of time. GAS-style inline assembly, although powerful, is *exceedingly* difficult to write correctly (I'm not even 100% positive that my code here is correct!), so you should not write anything using inline assembly that you absolutely don't have to. And this is *certainly* not a case where you have to—the compiler will optimize the addition loop automatically:

```
void addArray(float *a, float *b, float *c) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
}
```

With `-O2` and `-mavx2`, GCC compiles this to the following:

```
addArray(float*, float*, float*):
        xor     eax, eax
   .L2:
        vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdx+rax]
        vmovss  DWORD PTR [rdi+rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     rax, 512
        jne     .L2
        rep ret
```

Well, that looks awfully familiar, doesn't it? To be fair, it isn't vectorized like your code is. You can get that by using `-O3` or `-ftree-vectorize`, but you also get [*a lot more code* generated](https://godbolt.org/g/7IWRqZ), so I'd need a benchmark to convince me that it was actually faster and worth the explosion in code size. But most of this is to handle cases where the input isn't aligned—[if you indicate that it is aligned and that the pointer is `restrict`ed, that solves these problems and improves the code generation substantially](https://godbolt.org/g/kBIq42). Notice that it is *completely* unrolling the loop, as well as vectorizing the addition.

Comment: You are not writing to `a` you are writing to memory starting at whatever `a` is pointing to. As such, you don't need `a` as output but you do need a `memory` clobber. Also, even if you could get a syntactically correct `-16(%rsp, %ecx, 0)` to be emitted, that still wouldn't work because it would be missing a level of indirection. Finally, the shown C code while familiar, is unfortunately not vectorized, it's using scalars.

Comment: Oops, you're right, @jester. Thanks, fixed. You can get it to vectorize using `-O3` or `-ftree-vectorize`, but you get *a lot* more code. I'd need to benchmark it to verify that it was actually faster. Probably because I wasn't indicating that it was aligned.

Comment: "this entire exercise is a waste of time" - it is not. I've learned a LOT with this exercise. Thanks to you guys! You are the best.

Comment: Just for fun, nothing scientific, I did a small benchmark, running the routine 1 million times. I had to introduce an overhead dummy code in the loop to avoid the compiler branching the entire useless loop from the code. Compiling without any optimisation (-O0), my inline code takes ~120ms and the C (scalar) takes ~449ms (as expected). Compiling with -O3 -mavx2, my code takes ~50ms and the C (vectorised) takes ~58ms. Gcc does a very good job. The code it generates explodes in size, but it is very efficient.